Gstreamer: release RAM, when close and reload rtsp stream
I am developing a video wall for 36-64 streams, I faced the problem of increasing memory when restarting streams
I have an example illustrating my problem.
Example: https://github.com/Deymoss/Rtsp-player
When I start the application, a pipeline is created, as a result, the application initially takes 54MB of RAM, when I start the stream, the volume increases to ~ 110 MB, when I close the stream, the memory is not freed, when I run the same stream again, the amount of RAM increases to 120 MB, and so on, the same is true for file files descriptors (I suspect BUS creates them)
How to properly clear the memory and all information about the stream when closing?
At the moment I'm setting the pipeline to NULL and not making an unref, but if I uncomment these lines:
gst_bus_set_sync_handler(m_videoPipe->bus, nullptr, nullptr, nullptr);
gst_object_unref(m_videoPipe->pipeline);
gst_object_unref(m_videoPipe->bus);

nothing changes in memory consumption, although the refcount of each element and the pipeline itself at the end of the function is zero

I suppose you're looking at some process-inspecting tool, like windows task manager or linux ps? These do not give any useful information; pretty much every runtime library will hang on to memory previously obtained from the operating system for efficiency reasons. You just need to make sure you follow the rules set forth by the library for cleaning up objects. Sidenote: seeing your gst_object_unref calls, I suppose you should be making a smartpointer to wrap these pointers...

@ChristianStieber I'm afraid I can't wrap gstreamer elements in smart pointers, in fact, gstreamer elements work according to a roughly similar mechanism for counting references to an object, when the counter reaches 0, it deletes them.
As for the allocated memory, after a day of operation of the video wall, the memory reaches 5 GB, and unix destroys the process.

It's not a matter of "can", it's a matter of "want". Although, of course, maybe the "I don't want to" is forced by some other guy, that's certainly possible. Regardless, you're leaking memory, so you have to find the resource that you allocate without deallocating it. People often recommend tools that might be able to help; I don't generally have good experiences with those so I don't use them. Still, if you're leaking 5GB, even tools might be able to give some hints :-)

Inside componentComplete grabs the glsink element by reference. Although the link is removed later, does this cause memory leaks?
In the close function, try to remove links from all elements, and not just from the pipeline and bus.
void VideoItem::close() {
    
gst_element_set_state(m_videoPipe->pipeline, GST_STATE_NULL);

    GstState state;
    GstStateChangeReturn ret = gst_element_get_state(m_videoPipe->pipeline, &state, nullptr, GST_CLOCK_TIME_NONE);
    if (ret == GST_STATE_CHANGE_FAILURE) {
       
    }

    gst_object_unref(m_videoPipe->src);
    gst_object_unref(m_videoPipe->videoDecode);
    gst_object_unref(m_videoPipe->flip);
    gst_object_unref(m_videoPipe->videoSink);

    gst_object_unref(m_videoPipe->pipeline);
    gst_object_unref(m_videoPipe->bus);

    m_videoPipe.reset();
}

Implement Cleanup in messageHandler
GstBusSyncReply messageHandler(GstBus * /*bus*/, GstMessage *msg, gpointer videoItem) {

    switch (GST_MESSAGE_TYPE(msg)) {
        case GST_MESSAGE_EOS:
        case GST_MESSAGE_ERROR: {
            // Initiate cleanup process for the VideoItem instance
            VideoItem *priv = static_cast<VideoItem *>(videoItem);
            priv->close();
            break;
        }
    }

    return GST_BUS_PASS;
}


unrefs all children elements doesen't make sense because pipeline when reference count == 0 unref all its childrens.
